# Is there any way to preview freestyle lines using cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, freestyle

When using blender render freestyle lines will be previewed in the viewport while in render mode. This doesn't appear to be the case for cycles, but I'm thinking it is just an option somewhere that I have either unchecked or overlooked. If not, are there any addons or alternatives to previewing the lines without having to render every time?

Comment: Change to blender render while setting up freestyle? I don't think you are missing anything, it just isn't that integrated with cycles.

Comment: sorry it's late but thanks

Answer (score 1):

## No

As of 2.79, unfortunately there is no way to preview Freestyle lines using Cycles.

Comment: thank you. if anyone is looking this up in the future I just did what sambler said and previewed it in blender render and then did the actual render in cycles, although from other questions/answers it looks like you can combine one layer in cycles and one using blender render and preview that, but I never personally bothered